# Corrupted data in blob column after insert in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, delphi, blob

I'm trying to insert binary data in the blob column

```
PackedStr:=GZCompressStr(tmpStr);    

AssignFile(F,'c:\RequestHeaders.bin');
Rewrite(F,1);
BlockWrite(F,PackedStr[1],length(PackedStr));
CloseFile(F);

if SQLite3_Bind_Blob(Stmt,ParamNum,@PackedStr[1],length(PackedStr),0)<>SQLITE_OK then
  RaiseError('Error binding parameter', '');

 iStepResult := Sqlite3_step(Stmt);

if (iStepResult <> SQLITE_DONE) then
  RaiseError('Error executing SQL statement', SQL);

SQLite3_Reset(Stmt);
```

No errors, row inserted, but data actually stored in column don't match data in file.
I checked stored data with sqlite3_column_blob and with external tool, both return the same data with original size but data bytes has a lots of differences with dumped file.
GZDecompressStr can't unpack column data but unpack data from file witout problems.
How to say SQLite, store data as is without changing them?

Comment: Why don't you just use normal db-access components like DBX or FireDAC?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, value of PackedStr was changed beetwen SQLite3_Bind_Blob and Sqlite3_step, because SQLite3_Bind_Blob accept pointer as parameter, changes in PackedStr affects to stored data

Comment: So the code you provided here hasn't been executed by yourself at all? It misses the part where "PackedStr was changed between" which nobody but you knows...